# Trying to scrape this website using python but unable to get the required data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get the company names in this website https://siftery.com/microsoft-outlook
Basically it lists some companies that use Microsoft Outlook.
I used BeautifulSoup,requests,urllib and urllib2 but I still am not getting the names of the companies that use Microsoft Outlook not even in the first page of the website.

The code I wrote is below -

```
r = requests.get('http://siftery.com/microsoft-outlook')

print(str(r.content))
f=open('abc.txt','w')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

and part of the output that looks interesting is this -

({"name":"Marketing","handle":"marketing","categories":[{"name":"Marketing Automation","handle":"marketing-automation","external_id":"tgJ_49k7v4J-wV","parent_handle":null,"categories":[{"name":"Marketing Automation Platforms","handle":"marketing-automation-platforms","external_id":"tgJLE9aHoLdneT","parent_handle":"marketing-automation"},

BeautifulSoup also gives me the same output, so do the other libraries.
It seems like "external_id" is where the company name is ? I'm not sure. I also tried to manually find the name of a company for example Acxiom using gedit but couldn't find any occurrence.

Comment: The content you are looking for is generated after the page is loaded using javascript. I use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

That site loads the information using javascript that means that when you do the requests, the DOM is rendered without the information because it is loaded asynchronously, for sites like that you should use selenium.

Note:
Before you build a scraper you should look if the site has an api or end-points with CORS disabled, in your case you can get the information doing a post request to `https://siftery.com/product-json/<product_name>`

Comment: How were you able to identify that siftery.com has this json service available?

Answer (score 0):

The data is available directly as JSON. You can use requests to get it like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://siftery.com/product-json/microsoft-outlook')
data = r.json()['content']
companies = data['companies']
for company in companies:
    print(companies[company]['name'])
```

**Output**

```
Public Technologies
Consalta
PagesJaunes.ca
Chumbak
Media Classified
P.I. Works
Saatchi & Saatchi Pro
Tribeck Strategies
Marketecture Solutions, LLC
Trinity Ventures
ARGOS
CFN Services
Last.Backend
Saatchi & Saatchi USA
Netcad
Central Element
NextGear Capital
Masao
Avalon
Motiwe
Bilge Adam
Impakt Athletics
SOZO Design
ThroughTek
Abovo42
Acxiom
ICEPAY
Connexta
Clearview
Mortgage Coach
```

There are other categories of information which you might want to investigate:

```
>>> data.keys()
[u'product', u'vendor', u'users', u'group_members', u'companies', u'customers', u'other_categories', u'current_user', u'page_info', u'portfolio_products', u'primary_category', u'metadata']
```